# cv core:install throws an exception in Drupal 10

Tags: drupal

I use Drupal 10.2.0 fresh installed. I downloaded CiviCrm 5.68 with the commands

```
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
composer require civicrm/cli-tools
```

This installed civicrm/cv version v0.3.6

When I want to install CiviCRM with custom options the
cv core:install command throws an exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]    
Class "Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface" not found
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would have installed such an old version of cv - you need a newer one for drupal 9/10 - but in general you will have better results using the [phar](https://download.civicrm.org/cv/cv.phar) download of cv rather than trying to get it with composer.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The older version of cv was present in the search path from an earlier install. Composer installs the correct version of cv, the same version as from direct download. Thank you for your answer.